# Discontinuous Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP

$$ y' +p(t)y(t) = 0$$

$$y(0) = 1$$

$\forall\,t\in[0,1],\quad p(t)= 2$

$\forall\,t>1,\quad p(t)= 1$

Solve this IVP by first solving for t ∈ [0, 1] and then for t > 1 to obtain a continuous solution y(t).

I'm confused about how I'll be able to get a continuous solution y(t) ? Wont it also be discontinuous with these conditions?

Comment: There are arbitrary constants when you solve these differential equations, you can match the constants to make the overall solution continuous.

Comment: Solved it using the constant suggestion. Thanks!